# loopback Error: Model not found: Book : When I try to run after creating a new model using command

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, loopbackjs

When created a new model by generating slc loopback:model book,
When I try to run app , I got the following error

```
> Error: Model not found: Book at Function.registry.getModel
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/node_modules/loopback/lib/registry.js:273:9)
> at
> /home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:156:28
> at Array.forEach (native) at defineModels
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:151:23)
> at setupModels
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:140:3)
> at execute
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:28:3)
> at bootLoopBackApp
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/node_modules/loopback-boot/index.js:125:3)
> at Object.
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/server/server.coffee:24:1)
> at Object.
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/server/server.coffee:1:1)
> at Module._compile (module.js:409:26) at Object.loadFile
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:16:19)
> at Module.load
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12) at Module.require
> (module.js:353:17) at require (internal/module.js:12:17) at Object.
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/handlers/conditionchecker/brand_condition.coffee:5:7)
> at Object.
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/handlers/conditionchecker/brand_condition.coffee:1:1)
> at Module._compile (module.js:409:26) at Object.loadFile
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:16:19)
> at Module.load
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12) at Module.require
> (module.js:353:17) at require (internal/module.js:12:17) at Object.
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/common/models/question-group.js:13:3) at Module._compile (module.js:409:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js
> (module.js:416:10) at Module.load
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12) at Module.require
> (module.js:353:17) at require (internal/module.js:12:17) at
> /home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:170:20
> at Array.forEach (native) at defineModels
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:151:23)
> at setupModels
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:140:3)
> at execute
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:28:3)
> at bootLoopBackApp
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/node_modules/loopback-boot/index.js:125:3)
> at Object.
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/server/server.coffee:24:1)
> at Object.
> (/home/joseph/node_projects/laplace-master/enquete/server/server.coffee:1:1)
> at Module._compile (module.js:409:26) at Object.exports.run
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:154:23)
> at compileScript
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:224:29)
> at compilePath
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:174:14)
> at Object.exports.run
> (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:98:20)
> at Object. (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee:7:41) at
> Module._compile (module.js:409:26) at Object.Module._extensions..js
> (module.js:416:10) at Module.load (module.js:343:32) at
> Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12) at Function.Module.runMain
> (module.js:441:10) at startup (node.js:139:18) at node.js:968:3
```

Here is my model class and configuration file.

> book.js

```
module.exports = function(Book) {

};
```

> book.json

```
{
  "name": "Book",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "default": "1"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "default": "nil"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

and in server/model-config.json

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "sources": [
      "../common/models",
      "./models"
    ]
  },
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db"
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "mysql",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "mysql",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "mysql",
    "public": false
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "mysql",
    "public": false
  },
  "Book": {
    "dataSource": "mysql",
    "public": false
  }
}
```

Please help to close this issue.

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might have not initialized models in the datasource.

You need to run the following code in a boot script (save the code to `./server/boot/prepare-db.js` for instance. Give it the name you want but it must be inside the `./server/boot` subfolder.)

```
module.exports = function prepareDB(app, cb) {
    var ds = app.dataSources.mysql;
    ds.automigrate(function() {
       console.log("MySQL db ready");
    });
}
```

The `automigrate` function is documented [here](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#datasource-prototype-automigrate).